# Table Rate Shipping in Magento 1.7 with Wildcards not Working

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, rate

Magento 1.7 does not calculate the the shipping costs correctly when i upload a CSV with "*" wildcard in the "Country", "Region", "ZIP". Magento always shows the first shipping price even with cart subtotals above 500.

Is this a known bug? Did I do anything wrong? Any ideas?

my CSV: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2499022/TRS-WildCards.png

Comment: We have the same here, this makes me extremely anxious. It worked for a week. And suddenly just takes the first value.

Comment: we have same issue after upgrade from 1.4 to 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [guy](http://www.mrnordstrom.com/2009/11/23/table-rate-shipping-in-magento/) you must ALWAYS use country codes, otherwise PHP throws a notice of undefined index. We settled for the 3-letter country code and it fixed this issue for us.

Comment: I also found this, as it seemed that the table rates kept 'resetting' EVERY day, so I just did what this guy said and it seems to have solved the problem: http://spikomoko.wordpress.com/2012/03/11/magento-table-rate-shipping-not-working/

Comment: Yep, confirmed, the fix from spikomoko.wordpress... has completely fixed this issue since I added it. We haven't had any trouble since with the table rates reverting to the smallest value.

Comment: Table rate support '*' for country, the post you reported is old, the solution proposed it is impossible if you have 3 or more rules define d for all country ( you have to create each rule for every country )
It is probably a Magento 1.7 Bug