# Magento 1.7 - Shipping always 0, no matter what i enter

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

i hope someone can help me.

I have been using magento shipping table rates on magento 1.4.1.1 for months, it worked great.

Now after a update i always have 0 as shipping cost in magento, no matter how high the cost of the product is.

No matter which shipping option i use, it is always 0. Even at the flatrate option etc.

I dont know what to do anymore.

Cleared cache, reindexed, rebuild flatdata etc.

In every shipping option, the shipping cost is 0, no matter what i enter in the admin area.

What can i do?
Thank you so much for your help,

greets :)

Comment: do you use much or any custom code?

Comment: @Lucasmus: No, i guess not. Not many extensions, too.

Comment: Could be that an extension that might have something to do with shipping is not up to date for the new version?

Comment: You are referring to some update after which it stopped working. What exactly did you update / do ?

Comment: I updated from Magento 1.4.1.1 to Magento 1.7. Shipping worked fine. After some time, without doing anything, it stopped working, setting every shipping cost to 0. I used table rate based shipping but also tried fixed rate etc. There seems to be a bug with table rate based shipping in magento 1.7 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610138/table-rate-shipping-in-magento-1-7-with-wildcards-not-working?rq=1)... i dont know what i can try anymore :( Thanks for your help

Comment: Perhaps i can define the problem a little better now: I installed a new shipping extension. It worked the first time i tried it, correct shipping lets say 5 displayed. Now i have a product which applies for free shippping (over 100$), i get 0 shipping cost. From that moment on, the shipping cost stays 0 for every amount, every order....